# NSInvalidArgumentException on iOS 7.1 when downloaded from AppStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem with my iOS app when I download it from the App Store.
This problem only happens on iOS 7 and only if I try to download it from de App Store.

I've tested the same app AdHoc and on development and it works just fine.

The error message on the device log is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

The only change I did on my app from the previous version was to add Google Cloud Messaging support. But everything works fine on the others iOS versions.

The full log is the following:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  2

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x305c0f7e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ad71cca objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x305c0ec0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
3   Foundation                      0x30f03db6 +[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:] + 70
4   My App                          0x00113116 +[GMRIdentity iTunesMetadata] + 374
5   My App                          0x00112850 -[GMRIdentity initWithPersistedConfig:configuration:] + 648
6   My App                          0x0011416e -[GMRMeasurement startMeasurementWithDatabaseName:configuration:] + 202
7   My App                          0x0011a342 __38-[GMRScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueue:]_block_invoke + 86
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b25982e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b259de8 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 440
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b25a292 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 34
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b26c888 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 72
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b26cb1c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbce _pthread_wqthread + 294
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3058b846 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30589fb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 850
4   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x353fa65e GSEventRunModal + 134
7   UIKit                           0x32e41148 UIApplicationMain + 1132
8   My App                          0x000f390e main (main.m:32)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x3b27eab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b26dde8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b25cf6e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 34

Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3341f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39e792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b2e4fd8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a613cd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a62c6e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ad71f62 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a62a1c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a629a18 __cxa_throw + 112
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ad71d9e objc_exception_throw + 246
9   My App                          0x0011a3fe __38-[GMRScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueue:]_block_invoke + 274
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b259830 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b259de8 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 440
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b25a292 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 34
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b26c88a _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b26cb1c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbd0 _pthread_wqthread + 296
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3058b846 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30589f6c __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x30f35082 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x30faaa5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d916 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d886 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39baa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b334c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3058b846 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30589f6c __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x3878c1a6 RunWebThread(void*) + 414
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39baa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b333f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39cf22 _pthread_cond_wait + 518
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39dda0 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31522de8 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x31522c18 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x315202e0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d916 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d886 _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39baa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b334c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b321854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3058b846 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30589f6c __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x304f4c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x387d4bb2 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 250
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x315202e0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d916 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d886 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39baa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b334434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3058f708 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39baa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b334c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b334c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b334c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b334c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39bbda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39ba94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b333f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39cf22 _pthread_cond_wait + 518
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39dd60 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31522dba WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 58
4   WebCore                         0x388bf0a4 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WTF::Function<void ()> > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WTF::Function<void ()>*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WTF::Function<void ()>*), double) + 104
5   WebCore                         0x388bf02a WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 162
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x315202e0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39d886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b39baa0 thread_start + 4
```

Please, can someone help me with this?

Comment: The error is coming from the method `iTunesMetadata` in the `GMRIdentity` class - it's trying to load a property file, but the data that's being passed to the load call is not initialized - no idea where from with only a stack trace

Comment: The problem is I have no idea where the `GMRIdentity` class is. I'm searching for it and I can find it anywhere. Even if I google it.

Comment: It looks to be part of the google core API - I found a reference to it in `libGGLCore.a`. I know it's a long shot, but if you can get logs from the iOS device, you should check for warnings/errors in the logs just around the time of the crash. Unfortunately, I can't really help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for this!
We've just released version [1.2.1](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google) of the pod, that contains a fix for this issue.
Just run `pod update` to get the update.